# JQuery .click() not firing with JQuery 1.10.1 on IE10

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to add an onClick function to a div using jQuery. It works fine on older (1.9 or before) versions, but not on 1.10.1.

Really simple function:

```
    $(function () {
      $(".test").click(function () {
       alert("clicked");
     });
   });
```

have googled, but can't see anything saying the function is deprecated.

Full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/7da4P/

Comment: Works fine for me (Firefox 25.0). Which browser do you use?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on chrome. what's the problem?

Comment: Good point. Just tried Chrome and it worked. Was on IE10 before.

Comment: It's gonna be hard to reproduce the error, because jsFiddle doesn't work fine on IE10.